# Android - OSMbonuspack Marker not found

Tags: android, osmdroid

I cannot use OSMbonuspack markers since the import is never recognized

```
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker;
```

gives the error Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Marker' although I have both osmdroid(v 5.6.4) and osmbonuspack (v 6.3) in the project.

Does anyone know why can this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marker class was moved from osmbonuspack to the core osmdroid library some time ago. But the package was also changed to org.osmdroid.views.overlay ( [github: org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Marker.java](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/5c28a235f6d46241e225f7ce939090ef63ac403f/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Marker.java) ) so just change the import.

Comment: I have tried that, but I see no result on the map, even though I refresh it using
    map.invalidate();

Comment: So there will be problem elsewhere. I'm using this class without problems. Maybe check if you are adding Marker instance to overlays (mapiew.getOverlays().add(marker)) it is not  done automatically as far as i remember.  Otherwise maybe create another question ( "Why is my osmdroid Marker not displayed...) and post code you've tried there.

Comment: You're right the problem I originally thought I had is solved so thank you. I'll retry tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks for the answer :)